# Printing PDF on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

i am working in unity and i have a task of creating and then printing pdf from some of the snapshots taken through cameras in unity.

On windows after creating the pdf that can easily be done by calling the ShellExecute function and passing print as the parameter or using a function posted on stackoverflow i.e:

```
private void SendToPrinter()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
        p.Kill();
}
```

, but i have no clue at all how would i be able to achieve the same for the OSX build?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry? how can i achieve the task, i have no clue at all, a starters tip will be too helpful. i have never used a MAC and dont have a one either

Comment: No answer to the question but a negative point? reasons please? or am i not allowed to ask questions about things which i know nothing about?

Comment: Well, i know the folder structure is different from windows, the code i pasted is what i used in windows to send print command, i mentioned unity because thats what i am using, i am using unity's monodevelop to program the script using C#, so there wont be any relevence, i just need to know how will i pass a print function in mac, the code doesnt and the paths mentioned in it doesnt have to do anything with mac. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to look at Apple's "Printing Programming Guide for Mac". (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html)
2. To print a PDF page, you need a CGContextRef. In your views drawRect: method, you can get the the correct graphics context like this:

   CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
3. The method you use to draw a PDF page into a context is CGContextDrawPDFPage(context,page);
4. The easiest way to open a PDF document is to use CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL
5. You get the pages using CGPDFDocumentGetPage.